How to foundry test a function which uses 1Inch Swapping functionality?
I'm working on a protocol's Adapter contract. The Adapter contract have a function, which let users sell their PortalEnergy (assume tokens) to get ETH. They use 1Inch Swapping functionality to get this done.
The problem I'm facing is that I can't write tests for it. I mean I can't unit/fork test that the 1Inch swapping will work smoothly. I guess the problem is that I'm failing to create the exact swapData maybe to perform the swaps. If so, then how to create the swapData?
This is the function:
    /// @notice Users sell portalEnergy into the Adapter to receive upfront yield
    /// @dev This function allows users to sell portalEnergy to the Adapter with different swap modes
    /// @dev Get the output amount from the quote function
    /// @dev Reduce the portalEnergy balance of the caller by the amount of portalEnergy sold
    /// @dev Perform the type of exchange according to selected mode
    /// @param _recipient The recipient of the output tokens
    /// @param _amountInputPE The amount of Portal Energy to sell (Adapter)
    /// @param _minReceived The minimum amount of PSM to receive
    /// @param _deadline The unix timestamp that marks the deadline for order execution
    /// @param _mode The trading mode of the swap. 0 = PSM, 1 = ETH/PSM LP, 2 = 1Inch swap
    /// @param _actionData Data required for the 1Inch Router, received by 1Inch API
    function sellPortalEnergy(
        address payable _recipient,
        uint256 _amountInputPE,
        uint256 _minReceived,
        uint256 _deadline,
        uint256 _mode,
        bytes calldata _actionData
    ) external notMigrating {
        /// @dev Only validate additional input arguments, let other checks float up from Portal
        if (_mode > 2) revert ErrorsLib.InvalidMode();

        /// @dev Attempt to update the maxLock duration of the Portal. Requires 1 manual update to start
        if (
            PORTAL.maxLockDuration() > 7776000 &&
            PORTAL.maxLockDuration() < 157680000
        ) {
            PORTAL.updateMaxLockDuration();
        }

        /// @dev Get the current state of user stake in Adapter
        (
            ,
            ,
            uint256 stakedBalance,
            uint256 maxStakeDebt,
            uint256 portalEnergy,
            ,

        ) = getUpdateAccount(msg.sender, 0, true);

        /// @dev Check that the user has enough portalEnergy to sell
        if (portalEnergy < _amountInputPE) {
            revert ErrorsLib.InsufficientBalance();
        }

        /// @dev Get the amount of PSM received based on the amount of portalEnergy sold
        uint256 amountReceived = PORTAL.quoteSellPortalEnergy(_amountInputPE);

        /// @dev Update the stake data of the user
        portalEnergy -= _amountInputPE;

        /// @dev Update the user stake struct
        _updateAccount(msg.sender, stakedBalance, maxStakeDebt, portalEnergy);

        /// @dev Sell energy in Portal and get PSM
        PORTAL.sellPortalEnergy(
            address(this),
            _amountInputPE,
            _minReceived,
            _deadline
        );

        /// @dev Assemble the swap data from API to use 1Inch Router
        SwapData memory swap = SwapData(
            _recipient,
            amountReceived,
            _actionData
        );

        /// @dev Transfer PSM, or add liquidity, or exchange on 1Inch and transfer output token
        if (_mode == 0) {
            PSM.safeTransfer(_recipient, amountReceived);
        } else if (_mode == 1) {
            addLiquidity(swap);
        } else {
            swapOneInch(swap, false);
        }

        /// @dev Emit the event that Portal Energy has been sold
        emit EventsLib.AdapterEnergySellExecuted(
            msg.sender,
            _recipient,
            _amountInputPE
        );
    }

This is the test I wrote for the Mode-Zero, which works absolutely perfect:
    function testSellPortalEnergy_ModeZero() external {
        vm.startPrank(alice);
        PSM.approve(address(adapter_ETH), startAmount);
        adapter_ETH.buyPortalEnergy(alice, startAmount, 1, block.timestamp);
        vm.stopPrank();

        (,,,, uint portalEnergy) = adapter_ETH.accounts(alice);
        assertEq(PSM.balanceOf(alice), 0);
        assertGt(portalEnergy, 1);

        uint MODE = 0;
        vm.startPrank(alice);
        adapter_ETH.sellPortalEnergy(payable(alice), portalEnergy, 1, block.timestamp, MODE, "");
        (,,,, uint portalEnergyNew) = adapter_ETH.accounts(alice);
        assertGt(PSM.balanceOf(alice), 0);
        assertEq(portalEnergyNew, 0);
        vm.stopPrank();
    }

This is the test that I have created to test Mode-One/Two (the modes which deals with 1Inch swapping), which are failing:
    function testSellPortalEnergy_ModeOne() external { //TODO
        vm.startPrank(alice);
        PSM.approve(address(adapter_ETH), startAmount);
        adapter_ETH.buyPortalEnergy(alice, startAmount, 1, block.timestamp);
        vm.stopPrank();

        (,,,, uint portalEnergy) = adapter_ETH.accounts(alice);
        assertEq(PSM.balanceOf(alice), 0);
        assertGt(portalEnergy, 1);

        uint MODE = 1;
        bytes memory response = '{ "dstAmount": "18933897941780920", "tx": { "from": "0xc7183455a4c133ae270771860664b6b7ec320bb1", "to": "0x111111125421ca6dc452d289314280a0f8842a65", "data": "0xe2c95c820000000000000000000000005dad7600c5d89fe3824ffa99ec1c3eb8bf3b050100000000000000000000000017a8541b82bf67e10b0874284b4ae66858cb1fd5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c94a9ffe5a6357d9746000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003c8a407aee158c388000000000000000000000a3cc74aacc1b91b7364a510222864d548c4f80383a8db16d", "value": "0", "gas": 0, "gasPrice": "21500000"}}';
        vm.startPrank(alice);
        adapter_ETH.sellPortalEnergy(payable(alice), portalEnergy, 1, block.timestamp, MODE, response);
        (,,,, uint portalEnergyNew) = adapter_ETH.accounts(alice);
        // assertGt(PSM.balanceOf(alice), 0);
        assertEq(portalEnergyNew, 0);
        vm.stopPrank();
    }

The swapData/response I have generated is from here: https://portal.1inch.dev/documentation/swap/swagger?method=get&path=%2Fv6.0%2F1%2Fswap
// {
//   "dstAmount": "18933897941780920",
//   "tx": {
//     "from": "0xc7183455a4c133ae270771860664b6b7ec320bb1",
//     "to": "0x111111125421ca6dc452d289314280a0f8842a65",
//     "data": "0xe2c95c820000000000000000000000005dad7600c5d89fe3824ffa99ec1c3eb8bf3b050100000000000000000000000017a8541b82bf67e10b0874284b4ae66858cb1fd5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c94a9ffe5a6357d9746000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003c8a407aee158c388000000000000000000000a3cc74aacc1b91b7364a510222864d548c4f80383a8db16d",
//     "value": "0",
//     "gas": 0,
//     "gasPrice": "21500000"
//   }
// }

when I run the test forge test --fork-url $ARB_MAINNET_RPC_URL --mt testSellPortalEnergy_ModeOne -vvv, I just get reverts, no error msgs:
...
    │   │   │   │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: VirtualLP: [0x5615dEB798BB3E4dFa0139dFa1b3D433Cc23b72f], to: AdapterV1: [0xc7183455a4C133Ae270771860664b6B7ec320bB1], value: 990039483090608152906205 [9.9e23])
    │   │   │   │   │   └─ ← true
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← true
    │   │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   │   ├─ emit PortalEnergySellExecuted(caller: AdapterV1: [0xc7183455a4C133Ae270771860664b6B7ec320bB1], recipient: AdapterV1: [0xc7183455a4C133Ae270771860664b6B7ec320bB1], amount: 39521746941056707718716940 [3.952e25])
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   └─ ← EvmError: Revert
    └─ ← EvmError: Revert

Test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 24.62s

Ran 1 test suites: 0 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)

Notice that the test absolutely works fine until it reaches the 1inch code!
Pls help. Thanks!

Also, It will be quite helpful if anyone can pls share an example of a protocol which have written tests for the 1inch swaps. Thanks!
